# Move existing Foreign Key to different file group

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, filegroup

I used the following code

```
ALTER TABLE Table_name 
DROP CONSTRAINT constraint_name

ALTER TABLE Table_name 
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name
FOREIGN KEY (column_name) REFERENCES ref_table (ref_column)
ON [filegroup_name]
```

But I got this error

> Incorrect syntax near 'filegroup_name'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constraint is nothing but the rule made on the table.So create table in the FileGroup you wish.
Primary keys you may need to mention[filegroup name] along with the syntax since by default   CLustered index will get created. [Just in case if you want your index pages in different   filegroup instead of Primary filegroup]
Hence there is no need to specify ON [FileGroupName] while adding the foreign key constraint.

Hence go with:
ALTER TABLE Table_name
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name
FOREIGN KEY (column_name) REFERENCES ref_table (ref_column)